# Node js module.exports get object

Tags: node.js

I want to get the number calculated by this module, it returned an object.

```
module.exports = function calculate (s, key, k, d) {
  if (!k) k = 14
  if (!d) d = 3
  if (s.lookback.length >= k + d * 2) {
    let stochK = []
    for (let j = 0; j < d; j++) {
      let stochs = []
      for (let i = 0; i < d; i++)
        stochs.push((function(x, length) {
          let low = [], high = []
          x.slice(0, length).forEach(function (period) {
            low.push(period.low)
            high.push(period.high)
          })
          return 100 * (x[0].close - Math.min(...low)) / (Math.max(...high) - Math.min(...low))
        })(s.lookback.slice(i+j), k))
      stochK.push(stochs.reduce((sum, cur) => { return sum + cur }, 0) / d)
    }
    let stochD = stochK.reduce((sum, cur) => { return sum + cur }, 0) / d
    s.period[key] = { K: stochK[0], D: stochD }
  }
}
```

When I want to get the result of

```
K: stochK[0]
```

by calling

```
s.period.calculate.K
```

I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property "K" of undefined
```

What is the proper way of getting `K`?

Part of the importing code:

```
var calculate = require('../../../lib/calculate')

module.exports = {
...
  onPeriod: function (s, cb) {
    if (s.in_preroll) return cb()
    if (typeof s.period.calculate.K === 'number') {
    ...
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code that imports this module and calls it?

Comment: The original code is too long, I extracted the key part above.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

In your case `calculate` is the name of the function, so you must call the function for it to be of any use.

I'm assuming a lot here, but I have a feeling your code should be:

```
onPeriod: function (s, cb) {
  if (s.in_preroll) return cb()

  calculate(s, 'calculate', k, d) // k and d should be specified?

  if (typeof s.period.calculate.K === 'number') {
    ...
  }
}
```

In any case `s.period` must be populated or the function will crash. What the function does is manipulate `s.period[key]` so if you want `s.period.calculate` then you need to set `key` to `"calculate"`.